# Graphics2D JPanel Shows But Buttons Do Not?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, graphics2d

I have been trying to figure out how to add a Graphics2D object to a JFrame as well as buttons to the same frame/panel object. I want the buttons to be able to edit the image somehow, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting the buttons and image to appear on the same JFrame. Below is the code and the resulting window that I see, what am I doing wrong? And thank you for your time.

```
package carEditor;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CarIcon extends JPanel{

        public void paint(Graphics g){

            int x = 10;
            int y = 50;
            int width = 100;

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Rectangle2D.Double body
            = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y + width / 6,
            width - 1, width / 6);
            Ellipse2D.Double frontTire
            = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width / 6, y + width / 3,
            width / 6, width / 6);

            Ellipse2D.Double rearTire
            = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y + width / 3,
            width / 6, width / 6);

            // The bottom of the front windshield
            Point2D.Double r1
            = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 6, y + width / 6);
            // The front of the roof
            Point2D.Double r2
            = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 3, y);
            // The rear of the roof
            Point2D.Double r3
            = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y);
            // The bottom of the rear windshield
            Point2D.Double r4
            = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 5 / 6, y + width / 6);

            Line2D.Double frontWindshield
            = new Line2D.Double(r1, r2);
            Line2D.Double roofTop
            = new Line2D.Double(r2, r3);
            Line2D.Double rearWindshield
            = new Line2D.Double(r3, r4);

            g2.fill(frontTire);
            g2.fill(rearTire);
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
            g2.fill(body);
            g2.draw(frontWindshield);
            g2.draw(roofTop);
            g2.draw(rearWindshield);
        }   
        public static void main(String[] args){
            JFrame frame= new JFrame(); 

            JPanel jpb = new JPanel();

            JButton zoomOutButton = new JButton("Zoom Out");
            JButton zoomInButton = new JButton("Zoom In");

            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            //zoomOutButton.addActionListener(event ->
            //      textField.setText("Goodbye"));

            //zoomInButton.addActionListener(event ->
            //textField.setText("Hello"));

            jpb.add(zoomInButton);
            jpb.add(zoomOutButton);
            frame.add(jpb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.setContentPane(new CarIcon());

            //frame.pack();

            frame.setSize(600, 400);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setResizable(false);      
        }
}
```

Here is the result that I see:
[image: Car Image]

There should be buttons on this frame but there are none. Why is that? Thanks for your help, I am a beginner to Java GUI programming and I look forward to your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details about how painting works and how you should work with it.

The basic answer to your question is, you've broken the paint process by not calling `super.paint`, which will in turn call `paintChildren` and do a bunch of other really important stuff.

This is one of the many reasons why you should avoid overriding `paint` and instead favour `paintComponent` (and don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`)

> Not only these, check how he adds the components to the contentpane. I would say the main problem is that.

Thanks George.

You add the buttons to `jpb`, you add `jpb` to the `JFrame`...

```
jpb.add(zoomInButton);
jpb.add(zoomOutButton);
frame.add(jpb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Then you replace the `contentPane` with `CarIcon`

```
frame.setContentPane(new CarIcon());
```

You should stop and have a read of [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) to get a better understanding for what the content pane is and how it works

Comment: Not only these, check how he adds the components to the contentpane. I would say the main problem is that.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. It's a bunch of cascading failures 